# Unable to parse Commit Message in the Github Action

Tags: github-actions

I've been working on this for months now, but

I still can't parse the 'Commit Message' properly with Python (see script below).

You see, with every commit in my [repository](https://github.com/AndriousSolutions/mvc_pattern), every commit message begins with what represents the release's version number.

As of this writing, for example, parsing the commit message would result the a tag:

v8.11.0

I get this error message instead:
[image]

I'm not certain if it's creating the variable, tag, or not.

Python is not working for me. Would anyone have another approach?

```yaml
# This workflow tests and releases the latest build

name: CI

# Controls when the action will run.
on:
  # Triggers the workflow on push or pull request events but only for the master branch
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:

# A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel
jobs:
  # This workflow contains a single job called "build-and-test"
  build-and-test:
    # The type of runner that the job will run on
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    # Steps represent a sequence of tasks that will be executed as part of the job
    steps:
      # Checks-out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so your job can access it
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      # Use the standard Java Action to setup Java
      # we want the latest Java 12
      - uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: '12.x'
      # Use the community Action to install Flutter
      # we want the stable channel
      - uses: subosito/flutter-action@v1
        with:
          channel: 'stable'

      # Get flutter packages
      - run: flutter pub get

      # Check for any formatting issues in the code.
      - run: flutter format .

      # Analyze our Dart code, but don't fail with there are issues.
      - run: flutter analyze . --preamble --no-fatal-infos --no-fatal-warnings

      # Run our tests
      - run: flutter test --coverage

      # Upload to codecov
      - uses: codecov/codecov-action@v2
        with:
          token: ${{secrets.CODECOV_TOKEN}}
          file: ./coverage/lcov.info

      # Parse a tag from the commit message
      - id: get-tag
        shell: python3 {0}
        run: |
          import json
          import os
          with open(os.environ['GITHUB_EVENT_PATH']) as fh:
            event = json.load(fh)
            tag = event['head_commit']['message'].split()[0]     <----- tag NOT CREATED?!
      # Create a Release
      - uses: softprops/action-gh-release@v1
        env:
          # This token is provided by Actions, you do not need to create your own token
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        with:
          tag_name: v${{ steps.get-tag.outputs.tag }}                  <----- ERROR HERE!
          release_name:  ${{ steps.get-tag.outputs.tag }}              <----- ERROR HERE!
          body: |
            See CHANGELOG.md
          draft: false
          prerelease: false
```

Using an alternative approach, I'm able to produce a tag using the current date.

This proves that it all works expect when trying to assign a 'tag' value using Python.

```yaml
      # Get current datetime in ISO format
      - id: date
        run: echo "::set-output name=date::$(date -u +'%Y-%m-%d')"            
      # Create a Release
      - uses: softprops/action-gh-release@v1
        env:
          # This token is provided by Actions, you do not need to create your own token
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        with:
          tag_name: ${{ steps.date.outputs.date }}v${{ github.run_number }}
          name: ${{ steps.date.outputs.date }}v${{ github.run_number }}
          body: |
               See CHANGELOG.md
          draft: false
          prerelease: false
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`steps.get-tag.outputs.tag` is not correctly output in your workflow.

You should output it as described in the [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#example-usage-of-the-steps-context):

```yaml
      - id: get-tag
        shell: python3 {0}
        run: |
          import json
          import os
          with open(os.environ['GITHUB_EVENT_PATH']) as fh:
            event = json.load(fh)
            tag = event['head_commit']['message'].split()[0]
          print("::set-output name=tag::" + tag)  # <--- This line
```

Comment: No, unfortunately, that didn't work.  If you notice, the very 'print command' itself is returned and assigned to the variable, tag??

```
Creating new GitHub release for tag vprint("::set-output...
```

I'm thinking there isn't a way to retrieve a 'returned' value from a inline Python script as in this example.
There's just no way.